# Is everything an operator?

Tags: operator-theory

For example, I have some number $\alpha$ and a function $f$. Now I multiple this constant $\alpha$ with $f$ and get $\alpha * f$. Now I claim that $\alpha$ is an operator, $f$ my eigenvector, with eigenvalue $\alpha$. Why can't I do something like this?

If I could do this, then everything in my mind is an operator.

Can someone demonstrate a case whereby some mathematically defined quantity isn't an operator?

Comment: What is your definition of an operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28mathematics%29) in mathematics is defined to be a function between vector spaces or modules. So take an object like the singleton $\{0\}$ which cannot be a function as an counterexample. There are also many functions like $f: \{ 1,2\} \rightarrow \{ 1,2\} : x \mapsto x$ which are no operators because their domain or co-domain are no vector spaces.

Note: The concept of eigenvalues and eigenvectors are normally only used for linear operators of vector spaces to itself. For example the function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto x^2$ is an operator on $\mathbb R$ (due to the definition of an operator). This function is not linear, so that it doesn't make sense to talk about its eigenvalues or eigenvectors.

Comment: Eigenvalues and eigenvectors make sense for all maps from a vector space to itself. They just might not behave nicely, so we usually do not consider them.

Comment: Ohh, and the empty set is a function, just not a function between modules.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Really?! I didn't know that... Then I take $\{0\}$ because it cannot be a subset of an set $X \times Y$ and thus no map... Thanks for the corrections! ;-)